# Retrieving Amazon product reviews?

Tags: data-request, api, social-media, products, companies

I am currently working on a customer feedback project for brand products. I've used social media sources like Twitter and Facebook to get brand mentions, but I need customer feedback for particular products.

I've tried Octoparse to get Amazon product details but it doesn't seem to be able to collect customer feedback. Does anyone know of a method for scraping/collecting product reviews?

Comment: If you can't get it from amazon using their API (https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) it's probably not allowed.

Comment: @Swier - Ok, could you please tell me which amazon API should I use to achieve this?

Comment: Does [this question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4811259/6002174) help?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Thank you so much, I am studying the amazon API to collect customer reviews. But I am not sure is this API free to use or any charge?

Comment: I have no idea if the API is free to use; I have never tried. :-(